# how to put the image from mysql to php table cell

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have this code:

```
<?php
 $images = 'image';
 $sql = "SELECT image FROM items WHERE itemsID = '4';";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
?>

<div id="table1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:199px; top:139px; width:"241px"; height:"163px"; z-index:43">
<div class="wpmd">
<?php 
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
?>
<div><TABLE bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border=1 bordercolorlight="#C0C0C0" bordercolordark="#808080">
<TR valign=top>
<TD width=231 height=155><img src="images/<?php $rows[$images];?><BR>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>
<?php 
}
?>
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

this should be work but not

I'm putting an image get from the database then put it into table cell but I keep getting this error

[image]

Comment: I have provided with a comment how to display the image that is stored as BLOB type from DB.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro ! it works ! HAHAHA

Comment: You can accept my answer if it solves your problem. Since if the same Error is delivered by someone else they would fine useful for development purpose.

Comment: For accepting the answer you can have a look at this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. It is necessary for each and every one to accept the answer if the developer has solved your request. Glad to help you. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to display the image from the mysql which is storing the image name that you have uploaded you have to follow the steps in order to display it.

1. Ensure under which folder you have saved the uploaded image.
2. Make sure that you store only the name of the image into the database so that we can retrieve it very easy by looping it over the query.

> **Note:** As per the question you have to retrieve the images from the database so that you need to follow the code which i have given below.

**Method 1: To retrieve the image from the DB**

Your code which displays the `<?php $rows[$images];?>` is wrong pertaining to that you need to display the `name of the DB field over` to there and echo the value and then alone you will be getting the image over there.

Replace:

```
<TD width=231 height=155><img src="images/<?php $rows[$images];?><BR>
```

With:

```
<TD width=231 height=155><img src="images/<?php echo $rows['images'];?><BR>
```

> provided the `$row['images']` where `images` is the field containing the name of the image stored in the DB. or else you can change the name as per the Table field what you have. Rather than that your code look good.

Hence you entire code looks like,

```
<?php
 $images = 'image';
 $sql = "SELECT image FROM items WHERE itemsID = '4';";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
?>
<div id="table1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:199px; top:139px; width:"241px"; height:"163px"; z-index:43">
  <div class="wpmd">
  <?php 
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    ?>
      <div>
        <TABLE bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border=1 bordercolorlight="#C0C0C0" bordercolordark="#808080">
          <TR valign=top>
            <TD width=231 height=155><img src="images/<?php echo $rows['images'];?><BR>
            </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </DIV>
    <?php 
    }
  ?>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

**Method 2: To retrieve the image as per your Structure**

You have stored the `$images='image'`.

Ensure that the table has the field `image` where it stores the image name.
If it does so you can simply change the code like this .

> You are missing echo in the code so that it displays the name of the image stored in the DB and it prints that image stored under int images folder with the hep of the image name you given as input to the **img** tag.

Replace:

```
<TD width=231 height=155><img src="images/<?php $rows[$images];?><BR>
```

with:

```
<TD width=231 height=155><img src="images/<?php echo $rows[$images];?><BR>
```

**Note:** But method 2 is not advisable since if you loop through the DB for getting the value you have to follow that `Method-1` alone.

Comment: i tried that almost 100x and same thing happen >.< thanks btw .

Comment: You have stored only the image name in the DB right and the image under the **images** folder in your project

Comment: nope i also store the image in the DB using data types blob and when i selecting the image i only get the icon .

Comment: Ahh Good .. Pls wait for a minute. I wil provide you with a solution. I have done it already.

Comment: You have not mentioned that you have stored the image as BLOB type. If so you need to display the image which is stored in BLOB type you have to echo it as such below.

Comment: Try this code: `echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $rows['image'] ).'"/>';`

Comment: The one who has awarded with -ve credits to my answer can tell what is wrong in that so that i can rectify in future.

Comment: @NareshKumar.P You were missing closing tags in `</TABLE>` and `</DIV>` inside `while { ... }`, so your code for sure was wrong. I corrected it.